# Visual Studio database project with Firebird

Tags: visual-studio, firebird, database-project

I wonder if anyone knows if it is possible to use a Database Project in Visual Studio with Firebird? It seems that the DataSource in Target connection in the Deploy tab in the project properties is locked to Microsoft SQL Server and same goes for the "import database objects and settings".
It would be really neat to be able to version control and handle a Firebird database the same way I can version control and handle a MS SQL database.

If this isn't possible, does anyone know of a good way to version control a Firebird database? :)

Comment: Check out this [Daily WTF post](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Database-Changes-Done-Right.aspx) on "database changes done right".  I wish I could say I followed this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. This is only for MS SQL.

Actually you can still use it with Firebird, but you'll not be able to use 90% of features, because it's expecting MS SQL - connection to database or syntax or ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this Sourceforge project can help: http://sourceforge.net/projects/fbnetinstaller/ :)